# Upload image using lua

Tags: file-upload, lua, luajit, openresty

I have been trying simple image upload using lua and Openresty web framework. I found many solutions like

- [lua-resty-upload](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-upload)
- [lua-resty-post](https://github.com/antonheryanto/lua-resty-post)

Using lua-resty-post I got the form data now how do I upload it?

```
local resty_post = require 'resty.post'
local cjson = require 'cjson'

local post = resty_post:new()
local m = post:read()
ngx.say(cjson.encode(m))
```

As I'm new to lua I don't understand which one to use.
My requirement is very simple, I need a file attribute and want to upload on some place like in php [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). Is there any simple way to upload a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Using [lua-resty-post](https://github.com/antonheryanto/lua-resty-post).

**upload.html**

```
<form action="/uploadimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="upload" accept="image/*">
  <button>Upload</button>
</form>
```

**nginx.conf**

```
location /uploadimage {
  content_by_lua_file image.lua;
}
```

**image.lua**

```
local resty_post = require "resty.post"
local post = resty_post:new({
  path = "/my/path",           -- path upload file will be saved
  name = function(name, field) -- overide name with user defined function
    return name.."_"..field 
  end
})
local m = post:read()
```